# Moving element from a list of lists to StringVector

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to move character elements from list to a character vector using Rcpp.

```
Rcpp::cppFunction('
Rcpp::StringVector foo(Rcpp::List lst) {
    Rcpp::StringVector res(2);
    res(0) = "aha";
    Rcpp::List tmp = lst(1);
    res(1) = tmp(1); // fails to compile, tried different things including tmp(1).str()
    return res;
}  
')

# Excpected output
films = list(list("a"), list("B", "bingo"))
foo(films)
# [1] "aha" "bingo"
```

Comment: I would try `Rcpp::as<String>(tmp(1))`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent bingo! that works.